# Host a website using Wamp server for global access not just local

Tags: wamp, hosting, virtualhost, wampserver, web-hosting

**How can I tweak my wamp server to host a website to the world?**

I've been searching everywhere, but I can't seem to find the answer. All I find are post telling me to host locally to 127.0.0.1, but I cant find any post on how to broadcast the site globally.

I'm familiar with hosting a site on iis7.0, but now that I setup a wamp server I cant figure it out. I use dnsExit to point my domains to a dynamic ip address that stays auto-updated thanks to a dns exit ip updater program.

Can anyone please tell me step by step what do I have to do to broadcast a site to the world using a wamp server for windows 2008 server edition.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port 80 is open on your firewall and also port forwarded on your router to your PC.  That should be it.

To test, browse to your external IP address.  You should see your site.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Port 80 is already open, but what steps do I have to take to add a site to the wampserver? Do I need to edit the hosts file? Can you please go into more detail.

Comment: Don't you already have a site accessible on 127.0.0.1?  And no, the hosts file has nothing to do with.

Comment: Or is your _real_ question "How do I create a website?"  In which case I will vote to close this question.

Comment: 127.0.01 brings me to a local host site, how can I add a domain that will be accessible from any computer to the wamp server? What are the steps